# Converting file data to nested list

Tags: python, list, file, python-3.x, nested

I have a string of numbers that I would like to convert to a nested list. So far, I have

```
 with open('lifedata.txt') as f:
    table_data = [ line.split() for line in f]
print(table_data)
```

If the text document consists of numbers ordered like this,

`0000000
 0010000
 0001000
 0111000
 0000000
 0000000`

The code I have so far only creates a nested list that looks like, `[['0000000'], ['0010000'], ['0001000'], ['0111000'], ['0000000'], ['0000000']]`

But instead, I wanted it took be `[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[],[]]` and so on. I also do not know how to convert the string into an integer. I'm just very confused on how I should manipulate the original text document to do what I want it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what is happening:

```
>>> "0000000".split()
['0000000']
```

Instead, call [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) on every character in each string:

```
[[int(c) for c in line.strip()] for line in f]
```

Or, via [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```
[list(map(int, line.strip())) for line in f]
```

Comment: If I try to call every character, it gives me `invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\n'`

Comment: Oh wow that worked! So was line.strip() necessary to exclude the empty space?

Comment: @George in this case, it helps to strip the newline at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Use this ,it will return a list of containing data from each line of txt.

```
open('lifedata.txt').readlines()
```